# Mysterious UIColor behaviour with UIView and in General in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uicolor, swift-playground

Recently I came across an interesting(may be naive) problem regarding UIColor in Swift..

```
import UIKit

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: 0,
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50))
view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

let a = UIColor.systemBlue
switch a {
case .red:
    print("red")
case .systemBlue:
    print("blue")
default:
    print("unknown")
}
```

Following code prints "blue" on playground perfectly fine, but changing

```
let a = UIColor.systemBlue
to
let a = view.backgroundColor ?? .red
```

prints "unknown" in playground, May someone help what is happening here? I could not resolve it.. Is it something related to value type or reference type at some point?? Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried printing "a" to see what that says?

Comment: @DevKyle Yes, It's systemBlue Color, UIColor Instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing the two values gives you the explanation:

```
print(UIColor.systemBlue)

<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000b47880;
  name = systemBlueColor
>
```

```
print(view.backgroundColor!)

<UIDynamicModifiedColor: 0x60000058bed0;
  contrast = normal,
  baseColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000b47880;
    name = systemBlueColor
  >
>
```

When setting the `backgroundColor` property, UIKit wraps the color in a private class `UIDynamicModifiedColor`.

If you compare the resolved colors using the view's traits, you'll get `true`:

```
UIColor.systemBlue.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection) ==
  view.backgroundColor!.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection)
```

The resolved color is an absolute color:

```
print(UIColor.systemBlue.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection))

UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0.478431 1 1
```

A color such as `UIColor.systemBlue` is a dynamic color that might result in different colors, depending on the view's traits, which include factors such as high-contrast mode and dark/light mode.

From the [docs of `UIColor.systemBlue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173141-systemblue):

> A blue color that automatically adapts to the current trait environment.

Comment: Thank you, just saw it.. But..
1. Why UIKit wrapped it??
2. How may we access baseColor in same for comparison?
3. What is UIDynamicModifiedColor and UIDynamicSystemColor?? Any reference would be really helpful. :)

Comment: 1. This is UIKit's implementation detail. The view needs a way to hold on to the original color that was set and resolve it again when traits change. 2. You may only want to compare resolved colors with resolved colors and dynamic colors with dynamic colors, anything else doesn't make much sense. 3. These are private classes that shouldn't matter to the consumer. There's no documentation for those.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment. For a trivial case, consider Dark mode which tweaks colors to look better in different modes. For a more complex situation, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_changing_display_modes_on_apple_tv

Comment: Thank you.. Just seeing difference between fixed colors and adaptive colors..